# Compile Java source to another directory

Tags: java, linux, compilation, directory

so I'm fairly new to Java programming and I can compile and run Java code from the Linux terminal using `javac objects.java` and `java objects`. Although, I was wondering on how I could compile the source code to another directory? Let's say I have the file `person.java` in the `/home/alarm/projects/src/` folder, but I want to compile it into the `/home/alarm/projects/bin/` folder while still in my current directory. Not sure if that makes any sense, but can anyone explain this if possible? Btw, I am using Arch Linux just so you know my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `-d` to specify the target directory.

More information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options).